# How hide included models in sequelize.js?

Tags: sequelize.js

How to hide the includes models? I google it, and try `through: {attributes: []}`, but got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined`

I have virtual attribute `covers`

```
  ...
  covers: {
      type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
      get () {
        const result = []
        const covers = ['coverOne', 'coverTwo', 'coverThree', 'coverFour']
        for (let cover of covers) {
          if (isNotEmptyObject(this[cover].dataValues)) {
            result.push(this[cover])
          }
        }
        return result
      }
    }
    ...


     volumes.belongsTo(models.externalResources, {
      foreignKey: 'imageOne',
      as: 'coverOne'
    })
    volumes.belongsTo(models.externalResources, {
      foreignKey: 'imageTwo',
      as: 'coverTwo'
    })
    volumes.belongsTo(models.externalResources, {
      foreignKey: 'imageThree',
      as: 'coverThree'
    })
    volumes.belongsTo(models.externalResources, {
      foreignKey: 'imageFour',
      as: 'coverFour'
    })
```

I want to display only `covers` attribute, and hide coverOne/Two/Three/Four.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before you return the result, just omit those items using lodash.  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit

```
   const result = { ...omit(covers, ['coverOne', 'coverTwo', 'coverThree', 'coverFour']) }
```

Comment: Please, no. Don't do that.